# Apache / htaccess RewriteRule prepend each n-th character with something

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

One customer have working project based on `prestashop`. It use `.htaccess` file that describe all (additional) route mappings through series of strange but working **RewriteRules**.

Here there are:

```
^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
```

And so on … As you might noticed all trick is to map numeric part into series of nested folders. 
This awful mess of regex rules can be replaced with `(\d+)(\-[\w]+)\/.+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)` and replaced part might looks like `/img/p/$1/$1$2.$3` except this `/$1/` part.

So question is, is there any modifier or way to prepend each character in `$1` with `/`?

UPD: I find proper solution, that not so gentle but works just as expected

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/\d+[^\/]+\/[^\.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|png|webp|svg)$
RewriteRule ^(\d{1,5})(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?([^\/]+) $1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.%1 [C]
RewriteRule ^(\d)(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?([^\.]+)\.([^\/]+) $1/$2/$3/$4/$5$6.$7 [C]
RewriteRule ^((?:\d\/)+)(?:[\/]*)([^\/]+) img/p/$1$2 [L]
```

I couldn't find ANY documentation how chained RewriteRule worked. So. I'm guessing that it complimentary append tail part from test string.

Comment: Find posible solution: `RewriteMap sec "prg:[path_to_script]" RewriteRule (\d+)(\-[\w]+)\/.+\.(jpe?g|png|gif) "/img/p/${sec:$1}/$1$2.$3"`

Comment: It probably could be done using `N|next` flag but it also has unclear description, just as `C|chain`.